# Signing a SOAP Message in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, soap, message, signing

I'm implementing client application in Flex. And I'm connecting with some Web Service, which requires to sign every SOAP Message using specified certificate. Is it possible in Flex? Maybe some additional libraries?

Comment: as3crypto is pretty standard.